# Align text and images in a table

Tags: html

How can I align image and text in a table? Here is a screenshot of what I have done so far: https://www.dropbox.com/s/o8jxyt4w3lzddoc/table.png

I want the text to be aligned with the image!!

Here is my code:

```
    <tr>
 <td valign="top" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;     padding-right: 0px;">
 <img src="http://imgurl.png" nosend="1" border="0" width="21" height="21" alt="Line"     title="Line"></a>
 <span style="text-align: left; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; color: #000000; font-    family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size: 9pt;">text here</span
 </td>
 </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep your Markup and Styling seperate:

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://imgurl.png" nosend="1" border="0" width="21" height="21" alt="Line" title="Line">
            <span style="">text here</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**:

```
td span { vertical-align:top }
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/T6p5j/)**

Comment: +1 for stripping out the inline styles & mentioning it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `style="vertical-align:top"` to `td` like this:

```
<tr>
 <td valign="top" style="vertical-align:top; padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;     padding-right: 0px;">
 <img src="http://imgurl.png" nosend="1" border="0" width="21" height="21" alt="Line"     title="Line"></a>
 <span style="text-align: left; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; color: #000000; font-    family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size: 9pt;">text here</span
 </td>
 </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

In general to align two elements you can set them to `display: inline/inline-block` and them use `vertical-align` proprty:

```
img, span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6UBQZ/

Answer (score 0):

Use vertical alignment for an image as a middle. Below is edited code:

```
<tr>
    <td valign="top" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">
       <img src="http://imgurl.png" nosend="1" border="0" width="21" height="21" alt="Line" title="Line" style="vertical-align: middle">
       <span style="text-align: left; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; color: #000000; font-    family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size: 9pt;">text here</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```